# why is there large empty space at the top of my page?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in html and css and currently i'm working on a project.I don't know why there's large empty space at the top of my page.I have tried debugging as much as possible but i didn't get it.I'm trying to center the code horizontally and vertically but i just have a large space at the top of my container.Here's the code

```css
/*base styles*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    font-size: 15px;
}



/*Card Styles*/
body {
   position: relative; 
   background-color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}

  .container {
    width: 58%;
    max-width: 550px;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;


    transform: translate(-50%,50%);

 }

 main > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.9em;
 }

 .sedans {
    background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
 }
 .SUVS {
    background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
 }
 .luxury {
    background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
 }

p {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
   line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
    color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    padding: 0.7em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | 3-column preview card component</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="container">

    <div class="sedans">
    <div><image src="images/icon-sedans.svg" alt=""></div>
    <h1>Sedans</h1>
    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city 
      or on your next road trip.</p>
    <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="SUVS">
    <div><image src="images/icon-suvs.svg" alt=""></div>
    <h1>SUVs</h1>
    <p>Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation 
      and off-road adventures.</p>
    <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="luxury">
      <div><image src="images/icon-luxury.svg" alt=""></div>
      <h1>Luxury</h1>
      <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury 
      rental and arrive in style.</p>
      <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For some reason you have elected to position your `main` container using absolute position. I would suggest that you use an alternative layout method.

Comment: Just remove the absolute positioning, and the transform and apply `margin:auto`. Then it will be centered horizontally and start at the top of the page.

Comment: @Paulie_D Seems they also want vertical centering.

Comment: I don't think they *really* do. If they did they wouldn't complain about the gap at the top of the page.

Comment: They are doing `top: 50%` and then translating 50% (in the wrong direction).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By the inspect tool(right click / F12 -> the element tab), you can check the range that each elements covered.
Then you can know your element which has the class "container" already have space from top.
Next step, check class / styles attached on that class, you will find out the style making the space is

```
transform: translate(-50%,50%);
```

You can just modify the value to see is the one causing the issue, and change the value to fit your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really love it. You've even thought me how to use developers tools.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to vertically center `.container`.

Because the body's height is 0, `top: 50%` does nothing and keeps the `.container` at the top, then you are moving `.container` by half of its height down with `transform: translate(-50%,50%);`.

Give body the height of `100vh` and fix the transform to `translate(-50%,-50%)` and it will work.

```css
/*base styles*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    font-size: 15px;
}



/*Card Styles*/
body {
   position: relative; 
   background-color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
   height: 100vh;
}

  .container {
    width: 58%;
    max-width: 550px;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;


    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

 }

 main > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.9em;
 }

 .sedans {
    background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
 }
 .SUVS {
    background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
 }
 .luxury {
    background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
 }

p {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
   line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
    color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    padding: 0.7em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | 3-column preview card component</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="container">

    <div class="sedans">
    <div><image src="images/icon-sedans.svg" alt=""></div>
    <h1>Sedans</h1>
    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city 
      or on your next road trip.</p>
    <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="SUVS">
    <div><image src="images/icon-suvs.svg" alt=""></div>
    <h1>SUVs</h1>
    <p>Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation 
      and off-road adventures.</p>
    <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="luxury">
      <div><image src="images/icon-luxury.svg" alt=""></div>
      <h1>Luxury</h1>
      <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury 
      rental and arrive in style.</p>
      <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
/*base styles*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
    font-size: 15px;
}



/*Card Styles*/
body {
   position: relative; 
   background-color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
}

  .container {
    width: 58%;
    max-width: 550px; 

    height: 100%;    /* Here i adjusted the container height to 100% */

    margin-top: 10px; 
/* Margin-top so the top and bottom gets space and looks good */

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;


    transform: translate(-50%,50%);

 }

 main > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.9em;
 }

 .sedans {
    background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
 }
 .SUVS {
    background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
 }
 .luxury {
    background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
 }

p {
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
   line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
    color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:  hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    padding: 0.7em;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | 3-column preview card component</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main class="container">

    <div class="sedans">
    <div><image src="images/icon-sedans.svg" alt=""></div>
    <h1>Sedans</h1>
    <p>Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city 
      or on your next road trip.</p>
    <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="SUVS">
    <div><image src="images/icon-suvs.svg" alt=""></div>
    <h1>SUVs</h1>
    <p>Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation 
      and off-road adventures.</p>
    <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="luxury">
      <div><image src="images/icon-luxury.svg" alt=""></div>
      <h1>Luxury</h1>
      <p>Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury 
      rental and arrive in style.</p>
      <button>Learn more</button>
    </div>

  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see that the space at the top of the page has gone. Can you please [edit] your answer to explain what you did to achieve that. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center [answer].